Q-sharp syntax error in quantum HHL algorithm
Here is a snippet of a code I am writing in Q#(QDK by Microsoft) trying to program the HHL algorithm.
  operation PrepareBState(register: Qubit[], coefficients: Double[]): Unit is Adj + Ctl {
        let n = Length(register);
        if (n != Length(coefficients)) {
            fail "The length of coefficients array must match the number of qubits.";
        }

        // Normalize the coefficients
        let norm = Sqrt(Sum([x * x | x in coefficients]));

        mutable normalizedCoefficients = coefficients;
        for (i in 0 .. Length(coefficients) - 1) {
            set normalizedCoefficients w/= i <- coefficients[i] / norm;
        }

        // Prepare |b⟩ state using the normalized coefficients
        for (i in 0 .. n - 1) {
            Ry(2.0 * ArcCos(normalizedCoefficients[i]), register[i]);
        }
    }

However each time I get the following errors "syntax error: expected ), found keyword in(Qsc.Parse.Token)", "syntax error: expected }, found keyword for(Qsc.Parse.Token)" and "syntax error: expected EOF, found }(Qsc.Parse.Token)"
I wonder if anyone knows what those errors mean or how to fix them
I tried using list comprehension syntax in Q# to compute the sum of squares of the coefficients. I thought that this should resolve the syntax error on the normalization line. But alas, it does not.

Two of the errors are caused by the for loop not allowing brackets around i in range:
for i in 0 .. Length(coefficients) - 1

for i in 0 .. n - 1

The third one is caused by [x * x | x in coefficients]. Q# doesn't support this style of syntax. Instead, you can create an array of squares of elements of the given array as Mapped(x -> x * x, coefficients)
